# Private Chatter Group - File Sharing Settings

Tags: community, chatter, sharing, chatter-file, chatter-groups

In our Salesforce org, we only use Salesforce, Gold Partner and Customer Community Plus licenses. We use Salesforce + VF tabs community and we are still in Classic.

I am a System Admin and I am running File & Content Report to get the list of times a file has been downloaded in the entire organization / community. I am seeing a lot of inconsistent results because of the issue with access to files, particularly when the file is shared with another individual or a public group or if its a part of a private group. Is it still possible to get the results using Salesforce CRM? or I would have to use Wave Analytics / Data Loader to get this results for all the Chatter File downloads in all the communities?

The second part to this question is.. I created a private group in a Salesforce + VF tabs community and I have posted a file in the private group. Certain users are getting file Collaborator permission even though they are not part of this private group but part of this community. Users receive access to Community through either a profile or permission set. Could you tell me how to disable this for these users? System Permissions?

Answer (score 0):

To use the File Engagement report, you should join private groups as an admin.  You could potentially use a trigger on CollaborationGroup to add yourself to newly created groups.

I'm not sure what analytics our [Community Management Package](https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N3000000B5XHsEAN) provides.

For the second part of your question, can you please go to the file share settings to see how it is shared and with what access to the users?  The file may be shared with other groups as well.